# What is the name of this type of shelf support?

Tags: furniture, shelf

I've tried to use Google Lens but no luck. Trying to make some custom furniture with a pipe frame and these seem perfect for insetting a shelf.

[image]

Comment: That is probably custom made, but probably called a corner shelf support or glass table top corner support

Comment: There are bolt/screw on types.  They do not look hard to make, but I might get 5 good pieces out of 50 doing it myself.  Welding the flat to the main pipe is easy.  Welding the flats to slip on pipes and be perfect is the hard part.

Comment: @crip659, 1. That appears to simply *slip over* tubing, not bolted in place. 2. Why would it be difficult to fabricate? A simple jig made the same shape as shown would keep the cylinders aligned -- just disassemble jig to remove bracket.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  For a person who works or practices welding a lot it probably is not hard.  For the rest of us, repeating a good job over and over might be.  Welding produces stress that sometimes warp the metal.

Answer (score 1):

The part/s are common to the manufacturer.  There is no standard nomenclature for what you show in the picture.

If you are looking for something similar you may try googling "Tubular metal furniture"  Or try someplace that sells items to make projects like furniture.
Rockler is one company that comes to mind.

( I am not associated with the company and do not give any type of endorsement of their products. This is simply a suggestion of where to look.)